# ios devices screen overview

Tags: ipod-touch, iphone

I am really reckless and just dropped my ipod touch second time in past year and the screen is broken, I am not very keen on trying to replace it with flat fee, bacause I am sure it would happen again, what i want to ask is how resilient are the screens of iphone devices : iphone 3gs or iphone 4s, I am not sure about 3gs but it is fairly cheap where I live and 4s is too expensive howeever I already have shelved a lot of money trying to replace my ipod touch, I have a two year old wp7 device which is showing it's age so can anyone suggest a screen comparison, or buying a conver , protector is the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strength of the screen was greatly improved in the 4s. The 3Gs broke quite easily and alot of people weren't happy with this. My 4s has taken a hammering and still looks (almost) as good as new.